# Pattern matching over borrowed HashMap containing enums

Tags: enums, rust

I'm trying to learn Rust, so bear with me if I'm way off :-)

I have a program that inserts enums into a `HashMap`, and uses `String`s as keys. I'm trying to match over the content of the `HashMap`. Problem is that I can't figure out how to get the correct borrowings, references and types in the `eval_output` function. How should the `eval_output` function look to properly handle a reference to a `HashMap`? Is there any good document that I can read to learn more about this particular subject?

```
use std::prelude::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Op {
    Not(String),
    Value(u16),
}

fn eval_output(output: &str, outputs: &HashMap<String, Op>) -> u16 {
    match outputs.get(output) {
        Some(&op) => {
            match op {
                Op::Not(input) => return eval_output(input.as_str(), outputs),
                Op::Value(value) => return value,
            }
        }
        None => panic!("Did not find input for wire {}", output),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut outputs = HashMap::new();

    outputs.insert(String::from("x"), Op::Value(17));
    outputs.insert(String::from("a"), Op::Not(String::from("x")));

    println!("Calculated output is {}", eval_output("a", &outputs));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Review what the compiler error message is:

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
         Some(&op) => {
              ^~~
note: attempting to move value to here
         Some(&op) => {
               ^~
help: to prevent the move, use `ref op` or `ref mut op` to capture value by reference
```

While technically correct, using `Some(ref op)` would be a bit silly, as the type of `op` would then be a double-reference (`&&Op`). Instead, we simply remove the `&` and have `Some(op)`.

This is a common mistake that bites people, because to get it right you have to be familiar with both *pattern matching* and *references*, plus Rust's strict borrow checker. When you have `Some(&op)`, that says

> Match an `Option` that is the variant `Some`. The `Some` must contain a reference to a value. The referred-to thing should be moved out of where it is and placed into `op`.

When pattern matching, the two keywords `ref` and `mut` can come into play. These are *not* pattern-matched, but instead they control how the value is *bound* to the variable name. They are analogs of `&` and `mut`.

This leads us to the next error:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&Op`,
    found `Op`

    Op::Not(input) => return eval_output(input.as_str(), outputs),
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It's preferred to do `match *some_reference`, when possible, but in this case you cannot. So we need to update the pattern to match a reference to an `Op` — `&Op`. Look at what error comes next...

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
    &Op::Not(input) => return eval_output(input.as_str(), outputs),
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It's our friend from earlier. This time, we will follow the compilers advice, and change it to `ref input`. A bit more changes and we have it:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Op {
    Not(String),
    Value(u16),
}

fn eval_output(output: &str, outputs: &HashMap<String, Op>) -> u16 {
    match outputs.get(output) {
        Some(op) => {
            match op {
                &Op::Not(ref input) => eval_output(input, outputs),
                &Op::Value(value) => value,
            }
        }
        None => panic!("Did not find input for wire {}", output),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut outputs = HashMap::new();

    outputs.insert("x".into(), Op::Value(17));
    outputs.insert("a".into(), Op::Not("x".into()));

    println!("Calculated output is {}", eval_output("a", &outputs));
}
```

1. There's no need to `use std::prelude::*;` — the compiler inserts that automatically.
2. `as_str` doesn't exist in stable Rust. A reference to a `String` (`&String`) can use *deref coercions* to act like a string slice (`&str`).
3. I used `into` instead of `String::from` as it's a bit shorter. No real better reason.